# Facebook Like button not rendering inside a reloaded GridView

Tags: asp.net, facebook, updatepanel

I have a `fb:like` button inside the GridView and GridView is inside the update panel. The first time of page load the `fb:like` button showing but when we click the next button, on the next page the `fb:like` button doesn't render. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richard's solution worked fine for me. I shortened the code to:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandlerBerliner);
function EndRequestHandlerBerliner(sender, args) {
    if (args.get_error() == undefined) {
        FB.XFBML.parse();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Due to the fact that you are updating the page with an update panel, the like button will not be rendered when only part of the page is updated. You will have to attach to the clientside updated event (in JS) and then trigger the Facebook XFBML render command:

FB.XFBML.parse();

more about this here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

You can do this using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);

var _panels, _count;

function pageLoaded(sender, args)
{
    if (_panels != undefined && _panels.length > 0)
    {
        for (i=0; i < _panels.length; i++)
            _panels[i].dispose();
    }

    var panels = args.get_panelsUpdated();

    if (panels.length > 0)
    {

        updateFbLike();
    }
}

function updateFbLike()
{
    FB.XFBML.parse();
}


</script>
```

this is taken from this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163413.aspx

Comment: Dear Sir   i am using <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
and simply paste the   <fb:like  href='<%# String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}", "www.admissionJankari.com/Admission-in-" ,Eval("CourseName"),"-" , Eval("CollegeName").ToString().Replace("-", "=").Replace(" ", "-"),"-in-",Eval("CollegeCity")) %>'
                                                                                        layout="button_count" show_faces="true" width="100" font=""></fb:like> code in side the grid view where we have to write FB.XFBML.parse();

Comment: You only add this additional code once at the end of the page before the </body> tag